# How to add certain days to a known date with Active Record query in Rails 3.2.8?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There is invoice table in our rails 3.2.8 app. We want to select the invoice which is/is not overdue. There are invoice_date (date) and credit_term (integer) in invoice table. The idea is that if the invoice_date + credit_term (day) > Date.today, then the invoice is not overdue. Otherwise, the invoice is overdue. Here is the idea (not working query):

```
Invoice.where("invoice_date + credit_term.days > ?", Date.today)
```

What's the right way to add credit_term days to the invoice_date in SQL query? We would like to have a DB independent solution. Thanks so much.

Comment: You **really** should go through your nearly 200 questions and accept answers for some of them.

Comment: All good and valid answer have been accepted. We are not allowed to accept answer by ourselves.

Comment: I don't agree with you about your judegment. All good answers have been accepted. The ones with no acceptance are either our own answer or answers which can not solve the problem or not exactly helpful or not answer. Those who post question has the responsibility to tell which is the right answer so someone else can use the solution. For example, I don't want to accept your answer, because we are looking for a DB independent solution as we stated initially in our post. If I mark your answer as the one, it did not solve my problem or help to solve the problem. However I did up it for the work.

Comment: Good luck finding the help you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in no means an expert in ActiveRecord's query interface, but I was unable to find such a thing like what you are needing, without (1) making some DB changes or (2) filtering the Invoices "manually" (via a Ruby code).

Here are your options:

1. Instead of having a `credit_term` field, you can either:

   - Replace it with a `due_date` column, **OR**
   - Add the `due_date` column **and** preseve the `credit_term` as well -- this won't break any of your existing code, and, unless you got >100 million invoices, it won't compromize your production DB server.
2. You can add a searcher (like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), via [thinking-sphinx](http://pat.github.com/ts/en/) gem), and make an index for the Invoices. With a properly defined index, you can use Sphinx's query interface to find invoices meeting your condition (*if you want me to give you a concrete example on this, do tell me and I will update this post with it*). This approach has the advantages of:

   - Not changing your DB one bit.
   - Utilizing a *very fast* search engine with a search data which must be reindexed only once every 24 hours.
3. You can "manually" find the invoices you need via a Ruby code like this:

   ```
   invoices = []
   today = Date.today
   Invoice.find_each do |i|
     invoices << i if (i.invoice_date + i.credit_term) > today
   end
   ```

   Using `find_each` guarantees you that you are fetching the records in batches -- you are **not** fetching the entire table.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL *(you didn't specify your RDBMS)*:

```
Invoice.where("DATE_ADD(invoice_date, INTERVAL ? DAY) > ?", credit_term.days, Date.today)
```

Comment: We use Sqlite3 and prefer RDBMS independent solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do the date wrangling in ruby?

```
 Invoice.where("invoice_date > ?", Date.today - credit_term)
```

This is also able to use an index on invoice_date to run the query whereas MySQL (for example) wouldn't be able to use such an index if you used `Date_Add`

You may want to consider using `Date.current` (which takes `Time.zone` into account) instead of `Date.today` (which doesn't)

Comment: It returns error: NameError: undefined local variable or method `credit_term' for main:Object

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood - I thought credit_term was the same for all invoices. Have you considered storing invoice_date and due_date instead of invoice_date and credit_term (or in addition to)

Comment: credit_term is a column in invoices table and it is an integer. Add due_date may cause data persistence issue. There is a solution (using julianday) which is only good for Sqlite3. We want to find a DBMS independent solution.